# number of parallel connections to mysql

Tags: mysql, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to replace Amazon's SQS with my own equivalent SQS, which basically makes use of mysql for persistent storage of messages. Several threads will try to access mysql simultaneously. I've set MAX_CONNECTIONS parameter to 5000 in a 2GB RAM system. Will mysql allow 5000 connections to be opened in parallel.Or else, how many connections can mysql support?

Or is there any other better way to store messages persistently? Pls help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-use.html) you will find details on memory usage in mysql.
There are variables that determine memory consumption per thread.